# ¿Como hacer una función que retornara el mayor de los 3 valores?

Tags: java, funciones, double

```
   double  valorA; 
   double  valorB; 
   double  valorC;
   Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   System.out.print("Ingrese el primer valor: ");
   valorA = lector.nextDouble();
   
   System.out.print("Ingrese el segundo valor: ");
   valorB = lector.nextDouble();
   
   System.out.print("Ingrese el tercer valor: ");
   valorC = lector.nextDouble();
   
   double resultado = determinarMayor (valorA,valorB,valorC);
   
   
   System.out.println(resultado);
   
}
public static double determinarMayor(double resultado){
    double determinarMayor = resultado;
       if(determinarMayor > resultado)
           determinarMayor = resultado;
   return resultado;
```

Necesito realizar un programa que tenga una función que reciba
tres valores tipo double, y que esta función retornara el mayor
de los 3 valores. El problema lo tengo donde esta el double con el resultado.

Función : Recibe los tres parámetros. Mediante
bloques condicionales identifica el mayor.

Comment: Tu código está incompleto, tal como lo pones no compila. Te recomiendo poner un [mcve]

Comment: A parte de que el código está incompleto, tu método determinarMayor no hace nada, porque lo que estás haciendo es crear un objeto cuyo valor es un parámetro `double determinarMayor = resultado;` y luego, esa misma variable la estás comparando con sí misma (ya que resultado y determinarMayor tienen el mismo resultado); y por último, hagas lo que hagas, devuelves resutlado.. Por lo que revisa el código, complétalo y, si lo que quieres es analizar 3 valores, en vez de pasar por parámetros un double, pasa una lista, un array o un set y trabaja con eso.

Comment: Entiendo que es una pregunta para algún tipo de ejercicio para aprender a usar los ifs. Si esto no fuese el caso, una forma de obtener el valor máximo sin reinventar la rueda podería ser: `Collections.max(Arrays.asList(valorA, valorB, valorC)))`. `Collections.max` devuelve el máximo de una colección y `Arrays.asList` convierte varios valores en una lista (que es una colección) y así se le puede pasar al método max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas intentando guardar en la variable `resultado` el retorno de la función `determinarMayor` a la cual le estas pasando como parámetro 3 variables:

`double resultado = determinarMayor (valorA,valorB,valorC);`

Pero en el desarrollo de la función solo hay un parámetro y eso no es correcto:

`public static double determinarMayor(double resultado){`

Por ultimo en tu función `determinarMayor` no está claro lo que intentas hacer.

Te dejo un ejemplo completo para que veas como seria:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumeroMayor
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    double valorA;
    double valorB;
    double valorC;
    Scanner lector = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print ("Ingrese el primer valor: ");
    valorA = lector.nextDouble ();

    System.out.print ("Ingrese el segundo valor: ");
    valorB = lector.nextDouble ();

    System.out.print ("Ingrese el tercer valor: ");
    valorC = lector.nextDouble ();

    double resultado = determinarMayor (valorA, valorB, valorC);


    System.out.println (resultado);
  }


  public static double determinarMayor (double valorA, double valorB, double valorC)
  {
    double mayor = 0.0;
    
    if(valorA > valorB && valorA > valorC)
        mayor = valorA;
    else if(valorB > valorA && valorB > valorC)
        mayor = valorB;
    else
        mayor = valorC;
        
    return mayor;
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelente gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

tu funcion realmente no resuelve tu problema debido a que solo comparas un par de numeros, tienes tambien al parecer errores de sintaxis, deberias estudiar la declaracion de una funcion en java

```
public static double determinarMayor(double valor1, double valor2, double valor3){
double resultado;
   if(valor1 > valor2)
       if(valor1 > valor3)
           resultado = valor1;
       else
           resultado = valor3;
    else if(valor2 > valor3)
        resultado = valor2;
    else
        resultado = valor3;
 return resultado;
```

creo que podria quedar asi tu funcion

Comment: Excelente gracias por la ayuda.